# Why do we use a different web server for static files?

Tags: django, web-applications, web

I am a newer in web development.

**Why should I avoid having the same web server handle both Django and static media files, like style sheets or JavaScript?**

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony Yes, I always voted up when people answered my questions.

Comment: You need to actually mark an answer as 'accepted' by clicking the tick beside the question (meaning that the corresponding answer is the correct one).

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony thanks, just found it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a best practice, it is recommended to server static media files via a web server to make things faster.

Also, using a CDN enables content delivery more efficiently to users. The server that delivers content is based on a measure of quickest response time - network proximity(fewest hops) , availability, etc

You can read up more here:

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html